# not able to fetch recordId from currentpagereference

Tags: lightning-web-components, pagereference

I'm trying to get `recordId` from `currentPageReference`, I tried to get this from
also like this -

```
    this.pageRef = this.currentPageReference();
    this.recordId = this.pageRef.state.c__id;
```

but it's not giving any result on console.

This is my current implementation.

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class TBT_ClientSessionList extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    
    @api recordId;
    Session_White = Session_White;
    crossWhiteCircle = crossWhiteCircle;
    isClientSelected = false;
    eventId;
    userTimeZone = TIME_ZONE
    isLoading = false;
    @track user;
    @track dataToDisplay=[];
    @track ClientidData=[];
    @track clientData = [];
    EndSession;
    ClientId;
    Id;
    selectedEventClient;
    selectedEventInitals;
    dcCommunityUrl;
   // @track data=[];
   Session;
   clientURLId;

   @wire(CurrentPageReference)
cpr;

   connectedCallback() {

    this.clientURLId=this.cpr.attributes.recordId;
   // this.recordId = this.pageRef.state.c__id;
    console.log('record id from connected callback ',this.clientURLId);
  //   console.log('record id ',this.recordId);

// rest of the program logic

}
```

This is giving me only `name` attribute but I need `id`, for information - it's custom page built on experience builder but in URL id is there. any help/Suggestion is appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using wire method like this

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

@wire(CurrentPageReference) getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
        if (currentPageReference) {
            this.recordId = currentPageReference.state.recordId;
            console.log(this.recordId);
        }
    }
```